# Can i remove previous version of Google Chromes on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, disk-space

[image]

The picture was generated from space analysis app named **"GrandPerspective"**. I tried to free more space for my **Macbook Air** but what i've found in `/Applications/Google Chrome/Contents/` folder, As you've seen, These are about 30 **Google Chromes** with different version and all of them are take total 4.73 GB. So, why i have ask you **Is it safe or not to remove previous version of Google Chromes?**

Answer (score 4):

Those certainly should not be there. Chrome only keeps the last two versions.

What I'd suggest is that you simply delete the `Google Chrome.app` package entirely and install it again from a fresh download.

The fact that the old ones were not removed hints at permission problems. You may want to try [repairing disk permissions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560) and see if that fixes the underlying issue.